# Liferay npm-react-portlet reference error, module is not defined

Tags: reactjs, npm, liferay

So, I am developing React portlet for Liferay 7.0 CE. I have used blade command ( straight from the Liferay react template)

```
blade create -t npm-react-portlet -p fi.liferay.react.portlet -c ReactMain TestProject
```

Blade creates project as it should. After creation I changed to newly created project and ran

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

First time build prints

```
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
```

And after that

```
Execution failed for task ':npmRunBuild'. > Process command '<pathToProject>/build/node/bin/node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

-> Build failed.

When running again gradle build, build passes

When deploying to Liferay portal, browser console prints

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined[Learn More]
combo:1:1
Error: Load timeout for modules: TestProject@1.0.0
Stack trace:
require/</</s<@http://localhost:8080/o/frontend-js-web/everything.jsp?browserId=firefox&themeId=classic_WAR_classictheme&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files&languageId=en_US&b=7004&t=1521557570840:288:322
```

I am using npm version 5.6.0 and Node version 9.8.0 . Blade CLI version is 2.3.1.201711201552

Operating system is MacOs High Sierra Version 10.13.3

I have tried with new portal and with Google Chrome and Mozilla firefox

Answer (score 0):

It caused by the upgrade of liferay npm build tools.
It will be fixed after the new release of blade cli.

And you can also fix it by change your package.json file like the following:

```html
{
"dependencies": {
"react": "15.6.2",
"react-dom": "15.6.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-cli": "6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-liferay-project": "1.6.1",
"babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
"liferay-npm-bundler": "1.6.1",
"liferay-npm-bundler-preset-react": "1.6.1"
},
"main": "js/index.js",
"name": "npm-react-portlet70",
"scripts": {
"build": "babel --source-maps -d build/resources/main/META-INF/resources src/main/resources/META-INF/resources && liferay-npm-bundler"
},
"version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Hope that can fix your problem.

Comment: I have this exact package.json and I get stack overflow in liferay-npm-builder (Node process just keeps eating RAM memory until it breaks). Can you please explain what is the difference between this package.json and new/upgraded liferay npm build tools?